# T/F: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then argmax$_{x\in X} f(x)$ is a closed set.

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

I was asked whether the following statement is true and false.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then argmax$_{x\in X} f(x)$ is a closed set.

The provided proof that it is true made sense to me but I think I have a counterexample, which must be wrong but I am not sure why it is wrong.

Consider $(\mathbb{R},d_2)$ and the constant function $f(x)=1$, isn't the argmax$_{x\in X}f(x) = (-\infty, \infty)$ which is an open set?

Comment: The answer is in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But that's not relevant, since it is also a closed set. Every metric space is both an open and a closed subset of itself.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that property of metric spaces.

Comment: Not only metric spaces. In every topological space the empty set and the full set are both open and closed.